# Show that $f(A∩B)=f(A)∩f(B)$ is a false statement.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let's say that $$f(x): \mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}, \quad f(x)=-x^2-1$$
and $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb {R}$. I want to prove that $f(A∩B)=f(A)∩f(B)$ is a false statement.

For this, I changed the formula to $f(A)=-A^2-1$ and $f(B)=-B^2-1$. If $A=1$ then $f(A)=-2$ and if $B=2$ then $f(B)=-5$, so $f(A) \cap f(B)= \emptyset$. But doesn't $f(A \cap B)=\emptyset$ as well? I'm kind of stuck on this proof.

Comment: Hint:  $f(1)=f(-1)$.

Comment: Hint: read the question carefully. It says that $A$ and $B$ are *subsets* of $\Bbb R$, not *elements* of $\Bbb R$. You need to look up what "$f(A)$" means when $A$ is a subset --- it's not "just apply the algebraic expression for $f(x)$ to the set $A$ as if you could perform algebraic operations on sets."

Answer (score 2):

Take $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto 0$.

Then $$f(\{0\}\cap \{1\}) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$$

and $$f(\{0\}) \cap f(\{1\}) = \{0\} \cap \{0\} = \{0\}$$

In fact, for any function $f: X \to Y$ it is true that for $A, B \subseteq X$, $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A ) \cap f(B)$, but the converse can fail as you can see.

Note that the converse is true if $f$ is injective, which I leave as an instructive exercise for you.

Comment: The first part makes perfect sense but why does $f(\{0\}) \cap f(\{1\}) = \{0\} \cap \{0\} = \{0\}$?

Comment: $f(\{0\}) = \{f(0)\} = \{0\}$ and similarly for the other one. Note that by definition $f(A) := \{f(a) \mid a \in A\}$

Answer (score 1):

Pick
$$ f:\{a,b\}\to \{c\}; a\mapsto c, b\mapsto c. $$
Then $f(\{a\})\cap f(\{b\}) = \{c\}\cap \{c\}=\{c\}$. However, $f(\{a\}\cap \{b\}) = f(\emptyset)=\emptyset.$

In your case, analogously, you can take and constant function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R};x\mapsto c$ and then test two disjoint sets.

Comment: I think the OP's function is given to be $f(x) = -x^2-1$; but your method still works if you take $A = \{ a \}$ and $B = \{ b \}$ with appropriate choices of $a$ and $b$. (In fact, any nonzero $a,b$ with $a = -b$ will do.)

Comment: Yes yes, just look at the preimage of a number less than $-1$. You would get a second order polynomial. The singletons containing the two roots do the job.